# Lagrange Remainder the taylor expansion of $e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, smooth-functions

I know  $e^{-1/x^2}$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$, is an example of a smooth function that cannot be represented all the coefficients are $0$, but I am curious about the Lagrange remainder. Doesn't the remainder still approach $0$ because $n!$ grows faster than any derivative of $e^{-1/x^2}$. So in that case, since the remainder goes to $0$ as n approaches infinity, that would imply this function is represented by the Taylor expansion right? Am I misunderstanding the remainder theorem?

Comment: The remainder tends to $0$ as $x\to0$, certainly. However, for the Taylor Series to converge to the function, the remainder must tend to $0$ for **all** $x$ of interest as $n\to\infty$. The remainder, $f$, is constant for all $n$ and does not tend to $0$ for **any** $x\gt0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(\forall n\in\Bbb Z_+):f^{(n)}(0)=0$, every Taylor polynomial is the null polynomial, then the remainder at any point $x$ is $f(x)$ itself (for every $n\in\Bbb Z_+$).